# how to create deb or exe file of angular electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, react-native, electron

I am working on Angular 6. I want to create a desktop application of that project using electron. I have installed an electron in my project. when I create electron-build for development environment it is working fine and it displays the window. but I want to make desktop application for multiple platforms like Windows, Linux and Mac. I have installed electron-packager to create build when I create build for windows it shows me the error like 'install wine' and when make build for Linux create one bundle which contains a lot of files and I don't understand how to execute it. I want to create .deb, .exe etc so that I can easily run this app on any machine. I have tried `electron-installer-debian` as well but it throws description error, creating binary symlink error. I don't understand how to solve the problem.

```
// package.json

"electron": "electron .",
"electron-build": "ng build --prod && electron .",
"electron-packager": "electron-packager ."
```

[image: [1]]

Answer (score 2):

To build a Windows app (.exe) on Linux you need to install Wine 1.6 or greater, so that https://github.com/electron/node-rcedit can run. You should be able to do `$ sudo apt install wine64`.

electron-packager doesn't support building .deb files, it just creates a runnable binary of your app. There is another package for creating `.deb` files: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-installer-debian